# Sync with Onedrive

Tags: rsync, backup, synchronization

I would like to sync (and backup) my /home directory with OneDrive. I found some great terminal clients, where you can even mount your directory, but nowhere did I found an option to this with some form of a security protocol. (like ssh, sftp, something like that). I know that rsync has the option to do this, but only that..

Answer (score 1):

I've found [rclone](http://rclone.org/) to synchronize onedrive with an rsync syntax-like, but unfortunately it does not work for onedrive business... as far as i know there is no ssh connectivity with onedrive actually.
There is also [onedrive-d](https://github.com/xybu/onedrive-d-old) but i haven't tested it.

Comment: There are now (April 2018) two different OneDrive For Business implementations. I think that O4B-new is a superset of O4B-old and OneDrive (Home), but each month it seems to get more and more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Syncovery also can sync OneDrive Personal and OneDrive Business. Its Linux client isn't as nice as the Windows client, but it works.